# When scrolling, how to make an element fixed only within a specific section in Figma?

Tags: prototype, user-experience, prototyping, figma

What I would like to do is the following:

**When scrolling,**

- Make Element A appear in Section A & disappear in other sections.
- Make Element B appear in Section B & disappear in other sections.
- Make Element C appear in Section C & disappear in other sections.

---

My current situation:

**< Section 1 >**
[image]
**< Section 2 >**
[image]
( Right now, the orange bar is constrained because of "Fix position when scrolling" option.

I want to make the orange bar disappear after scrolling once.

At the same time, I want to make different orange bar appear at a different location.)

---

**I want to make my prototype look like this website** 
: https://www.greencar.co.kr/index.do (please look at green bars on the right side)

**< Section 1 >**
[image]
**< Section 7 >**
[image]

---

How could I make this happen in **Figma**?

Comment: I have the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to have all elements present in all frames. However, you can set their opacity to zero. Having the same names to the objects or frames will help smart animate work better.

Screenshot and video posted below for your reference.

Please let me know if this helps.[Reference Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6HkLO.png)

https://i.stack.imgur.com/5bXnR.jpg

Answer (score 0):

Use the **On Click** event together with **Scroll to** action, then specify the Target Frame to scroll to. Then set animation settings from Instant to **Animate**.

*NOTE: For this to be executed properly, you have to make sure that each section you scroll to, has the same height as your scrolling container.*

---

There is a Figma Playground file that teaches you how to do Section Scrolling as shown in the GreenCar website you've mentioned.

1. Get a copy of [Figma Scroll to Playground](https://www.figma.com/community/file/918189250907220365)
2. Study the slide entitled: **Scrolling a Nested Frame**.
3. Add a flow to that slide and click the Play button to see it in action. Scroll to the lower 1 2 3 buttons. Clicking on those buttons will cause nested frames to scroll into view.